# What defines how many arguments are valid when instantiating Ruby class?

Tags: ruby, class

I am reviewing Rails tutorial book and saw a part where it talks about classes. Here is an example:

```
class Word < String
  def palindrome?
    self == self.reverse
  end
end
# w = Word.new('madamimadam')
# w.palindrome? #=> true
```

Here I instantiated 'madamimadam' into Word class into `w` variable. Then I run `palindrome?` method.

I tried creating another method

```
class SomeClass
  def some_method
    self.reverse
  end
end
# s = SomeClass.new('hello')
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Why is it that I can't give argument `"hello"` on `SomeClass` but I can do it on `Word`? I never defined each class to take or not to take one argument.

Optional question: Why does Word is expecting 0 to 1 arguments? Where does it defined?

```
w2 = Word.new('hello', 'joe')
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, where you do not specify the parent class, the parent class is by default `Object`, which inherits its [initializer from `BasicObject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/BasicObject.html#method-c-new), which takes no arguments.

In the first case, the [initializer was inherited from `String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-c-new), which overrides the initializer mentioned above, so as to take one optional argument (i.e. you can write `String.new` or `String.new("foo")`). (It can also take two keyword arguments, `encoding` and `capacity`, but that is beside the point.)

If you wanted to replicate `String`'s initializer (one optional positional argument and one optional keyword argument), you could write this:

```
class MyString
  def initialize(str="", encoding: nil, capacity: nil)
    @encoding = str.encoding || Encoding::ASCII_8BIT
    # ...
  end
end
```

to define how many arguments `new` needs (if you define `initialize` on `Foo` with three arguments, you would instantiate the class with `Foo.new(a, b, c)`).

Comment: Just some comments on terminology: `initialize` is not a constructor. There are no constructors in Ruby. `initialize` is a method just like any other method. It usually gets called by `Class#new` but that, too, is a method just like any other method. The closest thing Ruby has to a constructor is the `Class#allocate` method (which also gets called by `Class#new`), but that, too, is just a normal method.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Meh. It's a fuzzy world. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)#Ruby) calls it a constructor. On the other hand, you are right: "constructor" job can be split into "allocator" and "initializer", which is what Ruby does under the hood by calling `allocate` and `initialize` from `new`, Objective-C does explicitly with `[[Klass alloc] init]`, and Java hides the allocation and calls the initializer the constructor. Changed to "initializer" to be more exact, but it is neither more nor less deserving of being called "constructor" than Java's.

Comment: I disagree. In languages which have a distinct concept called "constructor", a constructor is, well, a distinct concept. In Java, for example, constructors aren't methods, they have different dispatch semantics than methods, they have different binding semantics than methods, they have different inheritance semantics than methods. They are "special". In fact, the JVM bytecode for a constructor invocation is called `invokespecial`. In Ruby, `initialize`, `allocate`, and `new` are just methods like any other method. There is absolutely nothing special or different about them. The only "weird" …

Comment: … thing is that `allocate` cannot be expressed in standard Ruby without extensions, because it does things that are not part of Ruby, specifically allocate memory from the object space and set the class pointer. But that, too, is not actually special, there are other methods in Ruby that cannot be expressed in standard Ruby, such as `Module#append_features`, `Module#prepend_features`, `Module#private`, `Module#public`, `Module#protected`, `main::using`, `refine`, `Module#name`, and pretty much all reflection methods.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I think we'll just have to agree to disagree then. In my book, the only requirement for a constructor is that it is the primary way of constructing an instance of a class (or prototype) in an OOP language (special or not). JavaScript constructors are also not special, what makes them constructors is being invoked using `new` operator, but you'd still call any function that is _meant_ to be used with `new` a constructor. How JVM invokes one is an implementation detail.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Similarly, in Objective C, neither `+alloc` nor `-init` is special, and both can be overridden; convenience constructors is the commonly accepted name for regular functions that just call `+alloc` and then `-init` (like `[NSString stringWithCString:str]` being equivalent to `[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:str]`).